# Delete elements from a List using iterator

Tags: arraylist, iterator

There is a `List<Integer> tabulist` that contains values `[2,0,5]`.
Also, there is a `List this.getRoutes()` which contains keys `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`.
I need to delete elements `[2,0,5]` from `this.getRoutes()`.
So, as a result I must get the following entries in `this.getRoutes()`:

```
[1,3,4]
```

Here is my code:

```
iter = this.getRoutes().iterator();

while(iter.hasNext())
{
    Route r = iter.next();
    if (tabulist.contains(r.getRouteKey()))
    {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `r.getRouteKey()` is always 0. Therefore, I am always deleting the first elements from `this.getRoutes()`. I don't understand why the iterator does not move to [1,2,3,4,5].

How to solve this issue? Maybe I should also delete values from `tabulist`?

Comment: What's wrong with `routes = this.getRoutes(); routes.removeAll(tabulist)`?

Comment: @raina77ow Because List<Route> routes contains objects of a class Route. I need to delete the objects on the key "rKey". The values of "rKey" in 6 objects are [0,1,2,3,4,5]. So, I need to delete those objects that have "rKey" equal to [2,0,5] (tabulist).

Comment: I don't know why the iterator doesn't move forward, but why don't you create a function that accepts two parameters: originalValues and valuesToRemove? In this method create a new result List<Integer> and only fill this with values you want.

Comment: @Sigur: Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test my code, but here are 3 variations on the theme. You should test them in case I made a mistake, but they give an idea of the general idea.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Class1
{

public static List<int> RemoveItems1(List<int> OriginalValues, List<int> ValuesToRemove)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();

    foreach (object item_loopVariable in OriginalValues) {
        item = item_loopVariable;
        if ((!ValuesToRemove.Contains(item))) {
            result.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static List<int> RemoveItems2(List<int> OriginalValues, List<int> ValuesToRemove)
{
    List<int> result = OriginalValues;

    foreach (object item_loopVariable in ValuesToRemove) {
        item = item_loopVariable;
        if ((OriginalValues.Contains(item))) {
            result.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static List<int> RemoveItems3(List<int> OriginalValues, List<int> ValuesToRemove)
{
    List<int> result = OriginalValues;

    foreach (object item_loopVariable in from item1 in ValuesToRemovewhere (OriginalValues.Contains(item1))) {
        item = item_loopVariable;
        result.Remove(item);
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

The first one adds only elements to get to a result. Like I said in my comment.
The second one removes elements from a result that is set to the parameter Originalvalues. The last one is basically the same as number two, but uses LINQ.
I'm using static methods because then this can be used in any situation and you don't need to instantiate a class to do this. Which adds extra unnecessary code.